# Print layout with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, printing

I have the following page:

[image]

When I open the print preview on Google Chrome it will be like this:

[image]

And this is my CSS:

```
    body {
       width: 80%;
       margin: 0 auto;
    }

     #itinerary .actions {
        display: none;
    }

@media print { 
    body {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .hotel-amenities {
        -webkit-column-count: 3 !important;
        -moz-column-count: 3 !important;
        -o-column-count: 3 !important;
        column-count: 3 !important;
        padding: 10px !important;
        margin: 0px !important;
    }

    .hotel-amenities li {
        background-image: url("/images/check34.png") !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
        background-position: left !important;
        padding: 0 0 0 20px !important;
        background-size: 14px !important;
    }


    #itinerary .confirm-title {
        background-color: #115D74 !important;
        padding: 15px !important;
        color: #fff !important;
        border-radius: 5px !important;
        margin-bottom: 15px !important;
    }

    #itinerary .confirm-title h1 {
        font-size: 26px !important;
        color: #fff !important;
        margin: 0px !important;
    }

    #itinerary .confirm-title p {
        margin: 0px !important;
    }

    #itinerary .confirm-title #number {
        margin-top: 20px !important;
        font-size: 15px !important;
    }

    #itinerary .actions {
        background-color: #115D74 !important;
        padding: 5px !important;
        color: #000 !important;
        border-radius: 5px !important;
        margin-bottom: 15px !important;
        display: none;
    }

    #itinerary .actions .span3 {
        background-color: #F9F6F6 !important;
        padding: 10px !important;
        border-radius: 5px !important;
        margin-left: 0px !important;
        margin-right: 5px !important;
        width: 24.53% !important;
        box-sizing: border-box !important;
        line-height: 16px !important;
    }

    #itinerary .actions .span3:last-child {
        margin-right: 0px !important;
    }

    #itinerary .actions .span3 a {
        color: #000 !important;
        font-size: 12px !important;
    }

    #itinerary .actions .span3 img {
        float: left !important;
        margin-right: 10px !important;
        width: 30px !important;
    }

    #itinerary legend {
        margin-bottom: 10px !important;
        font-size: 19p !importantx;
    }

    #itinerary .itinerary-times > div {
        min-height: 20px !important;
    }

    #itinerary .itinerary-times {
        font-size: 13px !important;
    }

    #itinerary .itinerary-times .value {
        margin-left: 0px !important;
    }

    #itinerary .rooms {
        font-size: 13px !important;
        margin: 12px 0px !important;
    }

    #itinerary #phone {
        margin-bottom: 15px !important;
    }

    #itinerary .order-item {
        border-bottom: 1px solid !important;
        margin-bottom: 5px !important;
    }

    #itinerary .order-item.no-border {
        border-bottom: none !important;
        margin-bottom: 15px !important;
    }

    #itinerary .order-item.no-border .span {
        font-size: 12px !important;
    }

    #itinerary .order-item > div {
        min-height: 25px !important;
    }

    #itinerary .box-out {
        background-color: #115D74 !important;
        padding: 5px !important;
        color: #000 !important;
        border-radius: 5px !important;
        margin-bottom: 15px !important;
    }

    #itinerary .box-in {
        background-color: #F9F6F6 !important;
        padding: 10px 15px !important;
        border-radius: 5px !important;
        box-sizing: border-box !important;
    }

    #itinerary .room-confirm-number {
        font-size: 13px !important;
    }

}
```

[DEMO](http://wau.travel/en/?option=com_booking&view=viewitinerary&task=viewitinerary&tmpl=component&itineraryId=172617936&email=szamdev@gmail.com)

Any Idea what is the problem?

Comment: You didn't state the problem that you see in the print layout.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure why the layout not the same as the original page, they should be the same! Right?

Comment: Well, because a different print layout has been explicitly stated in your CSS using the @media rule.

Comment: I'm trying to find it but no luck, I searched all files for `@media print` but I can't find anything. I mean other rules not the rules added by me as stated in the question.

Comment: `@media print` style is defined in the html page source, of the Demo link that you have posted (<style> section on the main html page, not inside a linked CSS). If that is what you're looking for.

Comment: This code added by me, it's not the problem, I'm trying to solve this problem using this code, even if you remove this code, the page will still look the same no big different, I'm trying to find the other code

Comment: There are default CSS rules that are applied from the browser to print, just like to normal layouts. You need to override them if you want your own customized layout.

Comment: I'm already overriding them with `!important` using my styles above but none is working, you can check these styles.